# Can't copy files because file names are too long

Tags: sed, windows-7

I have an external HDD. The external HDD has only 1 NTFS primary partition. There are some files on it, but I have many folders. There are folders in those folders, folders in those folders etc...

When I try to copy the files from the external HDD to a NTFS partition on my internal HDD, some files are not copied because their file names seem too large.

Is there a way, for example, with a regular expression with the **sed** command or something to rename these files to smaller names. I was thinking of booting in linux, rename the files and boot into windows again afterwards. There is a problem with ~500 filenames, I can't just manually search for those files to change their name.

Sorry if I posted in the wrong place. I presume this is considered as a programming question.

Comment: Wait, both file systems are NTFS?

Comment: be carefful with special character like accent, space, ... from linux that don't use same character table scope as windows.

Comment: you still can  use a batch in windows using only small name (8.1 version) instead of full one

Answer (score 1):

Use Robocopy to copy the files! (Robocopy is ALSO useful for deleting files/folders that are too long.

Run this from the cmd prompt:

```
robocopy C:\source\folder K:\destination\folder /e
```

This just copies source folder to destination, and the /e switch copies subfolders, including empty directories.  [More info and examples](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The 255-character path limit in Windows is a legacy limitation that originated from the MS DOS era and was kept for compatibility reasons.

If you have Windows 10 Pro or Windows 11 Pro, then you can partially remove the limit via the Group Policy Editor and/or Registry Editor. Full support is still a work in progress, so you should also update your OS to the latest version if possible.

**Important note:** Because File Explorer uses an older Windows API, it's still subject to the path limit. However, third-party tools like [Git](https://github.com/git-guides/install-git) (and sed?) are able to avoid this limit. There are probably some visual tools that can do so as well.

To enable partial Windows support, go to `Local Computer Policy` > `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `System` > `Filesystem` and look for a setting named `Enable Win32 long paths`. If you don't see it, then you may need to check in the NFTS subfolder.

[image]

After that, go to the Registry Editor, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`, and create a regular DWORD entry named `LongPathsEnabled` with a value of `1`.

[image]

I'm not sure if restarting your PC afterwards is required, but it probably wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should always avoid making folders and files with long names and always give priority to use characters with no special encoding (for example always simple english characters).

In this case you need a way to fetch your data from your HDD with a tool because copy-paste won't work due to your cache memory being unable to load the file path information from within your OS.
If you use windows you can try recovery tools like "Active@ File Recovery"

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you copy a folder with a valid pathname <255 characters into a subfolder, making the total length of the pathname greater than 255.

For example I have a folder named
C:...\mypath\thecompletepathtothisfolderis254characters
and I move or copy it to:
C:...\mylongerpath\thecompletepathtothisfolderis254characters
Now the pathname is 6 characters longer and breaks the 255 character limit.

The solution is to move the folder back higher up the directory tree so the pathname is valid again. You can then rename it as a shorter name and move it back, or you can just keep it where it is.

With the 255 character limit not exceeded, robocopy and other software will then recognize the files.

Answer (score 0):

For people running into this error in 2023 and beyond who are looking for a quick, hassle-free, one-off solution for moving a bunch of files/folders from one directory to another without `robocopy`, the simplest solution I found was as follows:

1. Open the parent directory of the source and destination directories in Visual Studio Code.
2. Drag and drop the files/folders using the Visual Studio Code `Explorer` user interface.

This solves the problem of moving files without encountering the `file names would be too long` error. I imagine that any other popular code editor/IDE (or similar application) would work just as well as Visual Studio Code.

Windows will still encounter issues while working with the files themselves until the underlying error is resolved by reducing the length of the filenames or directory names. If you need to use Windows to interact with these files after you've moved them, you can use the same VS Code user interface to apply the remedy described in the answer by [Sammy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33093316/7654818) of reducing the overall pathname length by shortening the name of the destination directory or by relocating the destination directory to a higher position in the directory tree. Alternatively, you can follow the instructions from Sammy using the File Explorer in Windows, however, you may need to move your destination directory multiple times.